# Updating existing forms with pictures using php

Tags: php, mysql, image, post, edit

How do I update a picture in mysql? I already uploaded them and they are stored in the database already, however, i need to update them.

How do I remove the uploaded picture and replace it with a new one?

Or how do i just submit my update query with an empty file_get_contents();.

```
  echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['prod_pic'] ) . '" width="200" border="1px"/><br>';
  echo "<label for='prod_pic'>Upload Image:</label><br />
      <input type='file' name='prod_pic' class='col2' value=''/>
      <div class='clear'></div><br>";
```

and here is the updating_inv.php which contains the queries

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","12148qx3er");
$dbcheck = mysql_select_db("buybranded");
    if (!$dbcheck) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
$itemid = $_GET['id'];
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['prod_pic']['tmp_name']));
$sql = "UPDATE `inventory` SET
prod_brand = '$_POST[prod_brand]',
prod_name = '$_POST[prod_name]',
prod_category = '$_POST[prod_category]',
prod_price = '$_POST[prod_price]',
prod_desc = '$_POST[prod_desc]',
prod_quantity = '$_POST[prod_quantity]','{$image}', WHERE prod_id=$itemid";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
  }
header('refresh: 0;url=inventory.php');
$message = "Product Successfully Updated";
echo("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string, not for reading images

here's [a link ] http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
and for update images

```
<?php session_start();

function save($pic,$oldfile,$path)
{

$upload_dir =$path;            
$size_bytes = 9388608;

$extlimit = "yes";
$limitedext = array(".gif",".jpg",".GIF",".JPG",".png",".jpeg",".swf",".png",".Png",".PNG",".txt",".doc",".docx");
          if (!is_dir("$upload_dir")) { 
         die ("<center>The directory <b>($upload_dir)</b> doesn't exist"); 
          } 
          if (!is_writeable("$upload_dir")){ 
             die ("<center>The directory <b>($upload_dir)</b> is NOT writable, Please CHMOD (777)"); 
          }
                $file =  $oldfile; 
              if(file_exists($upload_dir.$file)){ 
                @unlink($upload_dir."/$file");//delete the previous file
              }
              $size = $pic['size']; 
              if ($size > $size_bytes) 
              { 
                    $kb = $size_bytes / 1024; 
                    echo "<center>File Too Large. File must be <b>$kb</b> KB. <br>»<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">back</a>"; 
                    exit(); 
              } 
              $ext = strrchr($pic['name'],'.'); 
              if (($extlimit == "yes") && (!in_array($ext,$limitedext))) { 
                    echo("<center>Wrong file extension. ");
                    echo "<br><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Click here to go back</a>"; 
                    exit(); 
              } 
              $filename =  $pic['name']; 
              if(file_exists($upload_dir.$filename)){ 
                    echo "<center>A image with the name <b>$filename </b>already exists change the name of your Image. <br>»<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">back</a>"; 
                    exit(); 
              }  
              if (move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'],$upload_dir.$filename)) {
                  chmod($upload_dir.$filename, 0644);
              } 
                  else 
              { 
                  echo "<center>There was a problem saving your file.<br>please try again later <br>»<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">back</a>"; 

              }

}

$con    =   mysql_connect("localhost","root","12148qx3er");
$dbcheck = mysql_select_db("buybranded",$con);
    if (!$dbcheck) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }


$permitted = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/pjpeg', 'text/plain'); //Set array of permittet filetypes
$error = true; //Define an error boolean variable
$filetype = ""; //Just define it empty.


$itemid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);


$result  = mysql_query("SELECT prod_picture FROM inventory  WHERE prod_id='".$itemid."'");
$oldfile = mysql_result($result, 0);
$directory_to_save ="images/";
$productpic = $_FILES['prod_pic']['name'];
if($productpic!="")
{
    $newfile=rand()*20000;
    $ext=strrchr($productpic,".");
    $newfile = $newfile.$ext; // here  your picture name is change 100008762396.jpg or whatever extension of file is uploaded
    save($_FILES['prod_pic'],$oldfile,$directory_to_save);
    rename("../img/productsimg/".$productpic,"../img/productsimg/".$newfile);
}

$sql = "UPDATE `inventory` SET
prod_brand = '".$_POST['prod_brand']."',
prod_name = '".$_POST['prod_name']."',
prod_category = '".$_POST['prod_category']."',
prod_price = '".$_POST['prod_price']"',
prod_desc = '".$_POST['prod_desc']."',
prod_picture = '".$newfile."',
prod_quantity = '".$_POST['prod_quantity']."'  WHERE prod_id='".$itemid."'";
if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
  }
header('refresh: 0;url=inventory.php');
$message = "Product Successfully Updated";
echo("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time @Noman, I pressed my update the product without uploading a new picture and it removed the current pic. now i am trying to upload a new one, but it only puts it in the images folder that i created but it can't show it or something.

Comment: I am using BLOB in my database, however if calling pictures from a folder is easier, could you tell me how to do it? @Nomman

Comment: it will remove old picture when you upload new.

Comment: dont think when upload picture to database it doesnot means that your picture is saving into database where as the one thing is save which picture name, for showing picture you have to do the same as you show in html, while the changes will be simple only get name of picture from database like this <img src="../img/<?php echo $recordset['prod_picture'];?>"/> this will be use inside the loop. if didnt understand simply paste your code i will let u know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually try it but it looks strange for me:
`'{$image}', WHERE prod_id=$itemid";`

You must indicate the column for the url that you got on your variable $image and erase the comma
`url_image='$image' WHERE prod_id=$itemid";`

Am I right?

Comment: I used the same query when i am insterting into database. but i do not know what to do when updating.